# Looping one file through another file in R

Tags: r, loops

Complete newbie here. I really need some help creating some loops (I am struggling getting my mind around where to even start). I have two data sets and I need to take an individual customer's ID and loop it through every row in another file and subtract the customer's ID from each row's value in the second file, and then output a new file that is customer ID distinct with effectively each row in the second file now a column in the new file with the subtracted distance.

Data1 is my customer file and I need to take each customer row and loop it over each row in the second file and subtract data1 from data2.

Data3 is how my output file needs to look.

Would appreciate any help :-)

```
data1 <- data.frame("ID" = c(1, 2, 3),
        "Var1" = c(377, 649, 592))
```

`ID Var1
1  1  377
2  2  649
3  3  592`

```
data2 <- data.frame("Class" = c("a", "b", "c"),
     "Var1" = c(444, 887, 437))
```

`Class Var1
1     a  444
2     b  887
3     c  437`

```
data3 <- data.frame("ID" = c(1, 2, 3),
         "a" = c(-67, 205, 148),
         "b" = c(-510, -238, -295),
         "c" = c(-60, 212, 155))
```

`ID   a    b   c
1  1 -67 -510 -60
2  2 205 -238 212
3  3 148 -295 155`

Answer (score 1):

Let's get you started. A basic loop uses the `for` command.

Try this out to see it.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
        print(i)
}
```

`i` is a variable I made up for an iterator whose value changes for each execution of the loop. What values will the variable `i` get? The ones in the vector `1:3`, a sequence of integers from 1 to 3. Inside the loop, I printed the iterator variable. You run this code, you see the output, and you have a picture of what happens in the loop.

Now you start filling in things to satisfy the question you asked. You started by saying you wanted to loop through two data sets. Your illustration assumes the rows are in order and they each use the same ID. Well, first how will you refer to a data value?

One way you can refer to the individual variables in the first data set is like this. The bracketed numbers address the row and the column of the data frame.

```
data1[1, 2]
data1[2, 2]
data1[3, 2]
```

Now you have some ideas about what to plug into the code for that simple loop.

Ultimately, for the kind of task you described you will learn how to join datasets on a key instead of by looping. However, that's not what you asked. You said you wanted to understand loops, so this gives you a jump start. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want. Simply loop over the data from file 1; within that loop, loop over the data from file 2. You initialize the data.frame and simply add a row with each pass through the outer loop. Important to note the use of `j+1` in the inner loop to put each calculation into the proper column in the `data3` data frame.

This code shows three ways of slicing the data from a data frame—using the column number (`data3[i,1]`); using the name of the column (`data1$ID[i]`); and using the column name in conjunction with the row number (`data1[i, "ID"]`).

```
data3 <- data.frame(ID=0, a=0, b=0, c=0)
for (i in 1:nrow(data1)) {
    data3[i,1] <- data1$ID[i] # or data1[i,"ID"]
    for (j in 1:nrow(data2)) {
        data3[i,j+1] <- data1$Var1[i] - data2$Var1[j]
    }
}
```